# In Aquamacs, don't capture certain key combinations

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, aquamacs

I have set up a global shortcut to do something on my Mac (open up AckMate), the only problem is that within Aquamacs it still captures the key combination as an Emacs command (and says cmd+ctrl+f is undefined). 
Is there a way to get Aquamcs to ignore this key combination and allow my Mac keyboard shortcut to get activated?

Answer (score 0):

Aquamacs intercepts all keyboard input in its editor before triggering menu items, which is how you implemented your "global hotkey". You'll notice that pressing e.g. `Command-N` or `Command-W` does not flash the related menu bar item, like in any other application. You also cannot reassign keyboard shortcuts using *System Preferences* like in almost any other application.

You need a third party application, such as [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) or [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), that selectively intercepts keyboard input even before it reaches your application, and implement your keyboard shortcut independent from regular menu item keyboard shortcuts.